# Align text boxes in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, alignment

I have a PDF with a table on contents where each line is it's own text box object. I want to align these objects with each other but I can't find a way to do this. There is no "align" command and I can't edit the X-Y location properties of the object.

The only method that I found was to put a guideline on the page and manually drag objects around to get them to line up. This is both a terrible waste of time and doesn't work right.

When I search for help, everything relates back to Acrobat 10 which is no use to me. For some stupid reason, the adobe help documents are only written for Acrobat X.

Comment: Have you found any solution so far?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this if anyone still encounters the issue follow steps below:

1. Select text boxes you want to align.
2. Right click> choose center> Horizontally. This will center all text boxes on the page.
3. Select the text boxes again
4. Right Click> choose align> align left. this will align the objects to one another.
5. now select all text boxes together, and move it over to the desired spot on your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "select object" tool (the icon/button looks like a regular black mouse pointer) and select all of the text boxes. Right click on the selected text boxes and you should see an "align" sub menu in the context menu.

Comment: That works for "interactive objects" but text boxes are not interactive so that selector can't select it.

Comment: Gotcha. How were the text boxes created? My method will work with text boxes added via the comment tools and the typewriter tool.

Comment: I believe they were created when the document was converted from a word processor (I'm assuming Microsoft Word) document to PDF. I'm not all that sure how that conversion happened.

Comment: Acrobat is not really made for editing PDF content. Try extracting the contents page(s) from the PDF, converting it to Word, and editing it there. Otherwise, you can edit the PDF in InDesign.

Comment: I don't see any align in the context menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBZzP.png  the text boxes were created using "add text" in the content editing section.

Answer (score 0):

How to Align text in Text box in Acrobat XI:

1. Select Text in the Text Box
2. Enter CTRL+E
3. A pop-up menu opens which has an option to align the text.